What happened to Black Dog?
What happened to Black Dog after we see him in the early part of Treasure Island (1950)?
As far as I understand from the books and the movies, nearly all of the old pirate crew was on the voyage to Treasure Island by showing themselves as just they were regular seamen.
Can I assume that Black Dog had bad luck losing the ticket to the voyage and didn't join the crew?

In the novel we see him being chased away,  not to return.
